# Login post request does not work

Tags: jmeter

I had a look at similar questions here, but did not find any dynamic parameter, session information etc which I need to get around using regular expression extractor to login post request. 
The Network traffic on chrome seems same.
JMeter seems to pass all required parameters and and I also have HTTP cookie manager set up (as depicted in snapshot).

here is the [JMX script](http://justpaste.it/zalandoLogin). I have struggled with this seemingly simple use case for 1 day have been clueless so far.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some dynamic parameters.

To make it work,

1. Send a simple HTTP request to `www.zalando.de/login`

`<input type="hidden" name="_sourcePage" value="WWScWmVVYn3uSAjDV0VmRUaxY8np_Kj8XwbKjpAM6Z4ZBx3a1i4qrAt340nPsm8WoPocLW1Uvy0=" /><input type="hidden" name="_xtk" value="A2tPiZQsZqyptrUdhhTxOxhmbJsyjPgwchzLFZyz41iFfo4uDoSYO0cYIR7gls6M" /><input type="hidden" name="__fp" value="47Scl-SCdBc=" />`

2. From the HTTP response, Extract `__fp`, `_sourcePage`, `_xtk`
3. Send the login request by updating these values in thr HTTP request.

It should work now.